# mocha pass variable to the next test

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js

```
describe('some test', function(){
    // Could put here a shared variable
    it('should pass a value', function(done){
        done(null, 1);
    });
    it('and then double it', function(value, done){
        console.log(value * 2);
        done();
    });
});
```

The above currently would not work in mocha.

A solution would be to have a variable shared between the tests, as shown above.

With `async.waterfall()` this is very possible and I really like it. Is there any way to make it happen in mocha?

Thanks!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It is much preferable to keep the tests isolated so that one test does not depend on a computation performed in another. Let's call the test that should pass a value test A and the test that should get it test B. Some question to consider:

1. Are test A and test B really two different tests? If not, they could be combined.
2. Is test A meant to provide test B with a fixture to test against? If so, test A should become the callback for a `before` or `beforeEach` call. You basically pass the data around by assigning it to variables in the closure of `describe`.

   ```
   describe('some test', function(){
       var fixture;

       before(function(done){
           fixture = ...;
           done();
       });

       it('do something', function(done){
           fixture.blah(...);
           done();
       });
   });
   ```

I've read Mocha's code, and provided I'm not forgetting something, there is no way to call `describe`, `it`, or the `done` callback to pass values around. So the method above is it.

Comment: What about nested describes? I get an access token in a before() method that almost every subsequent test needs to use.

Answer (score 12):

Very much agree with what Louis said, and those are the reasons that Mocha doesn't actually support it. Think of the async method you referenced; if your first test fails you get a waterfall failure across the rest of them.

Your only way to go about it is, as you say, to stick a variable at the top:

```
describe('some test', function(){
    var value = 0;
    it('should pass a value', function(done){
        value = 5;
        done();
    });
    it('and then double it', function(done){
        console.log(value * 2); // 10
        done();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, a small fix to your statement (quoting async's docs): `if any of the functions pass an error to the callback, the next function is not executed and the main callback is immediately called with the error`... But thank you though

Comment: Yeah, but the issue with that method is you then cancel any execution of the following tests altogether, rather than failing the first test and continuing onto the next stage - does that make sense?

Comment: @AnthonyMayfield post some code? :) maybe in a gist.

Comment: Think I've figured it out now! In your example both tests are synchronous, in my case I'm trying to update the variable after running some async. Pretty sure I need to use Mocha's after method, reading up the docs on that now. Thanks for the offer though :)

Comment: Nope, turns out the describe suites are run in sequential order. Mystery solved! Haha

Comment: My issue with all this is that I have each subtest (the 'it' callbacks) in separate files which I then include. It all goes well until you need to start a session, then run through a series of tests. I'd like to be able to save the session (for example using the agent feature) but it's just not possible it seems.

Answer (score 9):

It is also possible to add to the suit or context object.

In this example, It's added to the suit object

```
describe('suit', function(){
    before(() => {
        this.suitData = 'suit';
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
        this.testData = 'test';
    });


    it('test', done => {
         console.log(this.suitData)// => suit
         console.log(this.testData)// => test
    })
});
```

Comment: Be aware that the `this` here is a different `this` to if you were not using arrow functions... I think.  (At least, in my case, what I was trying to do didn't work, until I realized I was mixing arrow and normal functions.)  mocha recommends to not use arrow functions: https://mochajs.org/#arrow-functions

Comment: this is correct. This will work only with arrow functions.

Comment: And a wrap of a non-arrow function