# share variables between mocha initializations and actual tests

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

Look at the sample:

```
var app
describe('application', function() {
  beforeEach(function(done) {
    app = initialize()
  });

  afterEach(function(done) {
    app.close(done)
  });

  it('some interaction with app', function () {
    ///
  });
});
```

`app` is the global variable which is bad from style perspective and makes `initialize` not so useful.
Is there are better way to share `app` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [share behaviours](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Shared-Behaviours)

> Mocha currently has no concept of a "shared behaviour" however the "contexts" facilitate this feature.

So for your case, it could be done as below,

```
describe('application', function() {
  var app;
  beforeEach(function(done) {
    app = initialize()
  });

  afterEach(function(done) {
    app.close(done)
  });

  it('some interaction with app', function () {
    ///
  });
});
```

BTW, sort of same question is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20586409/3011380)