# Test functions inside an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, mocha.js

When testing functions inside an object, how do you pass in the variable value in Mocha?

For example:

foo.js

```
const a = {
  vars: {name:"James"},
  output() {
   console.log(this.vars.name)
  }
}
```

How do you test the function output and have test cases with different name value?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a value in by assigning it to the variable (i.e. `name`) inside a `describe()` call.  See [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20586409/5463636) for an example of how to do that.

> ```
> describe('some test', function(){
>     var fixture;
>
>     before(function(done){
>         fixture = ...;
>         done();
>     });
>
>     it('do something', function(done){
>         fixture.blah(...);
>         done();
>     });
> });
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Just assign it in your test case

`a.js`

```
const a = {
  vars: {name:"James"},
  output() {
    return this.vars.name
  }
}

module.exports = a
```

`a.test.js`

```
const a = require('./a.js')

var assert = require('assert');

describe('aTest', function() {
  it('nameA', function() {
    a.vars = {name: "A"}
    // console.log(a.output())
    assert.equal(a.output(), "A")
  });
  it('nameB', function() {
    a.vars = {name: "B"}
    assert.equal(a.output(), "B")
  });
});
```